# Роли пользователей в Anularjs, как правильно разграничить права?

Tags: angularjs, auth

Суть вопроса такова, есть клиентское spa angularjs, есть api server на laravel.
На сайте есть личный кабинет, который делиться на 3 вида пользователей:

- user (profile/*)
- admin (admin/*)
- manager (manager/*)

Так как функционал кабинета большой, решил разделить кабинеты на отдельные модули со своими вьюхами, роутингом и т.д.
После авторизации мы должны получить данные о пользователе и открыть ему соответствующий url, равный его роли и работать только с этой моделью кабинета.

Как лучше организовать проверку прав пользователя и дать ему соответствующий кабинет? Авторизация происходит по токену.

1. Брать из данных пользователя с сервера его роль, записывать в сессию или куки и по ним давать доступ? Но это не разу не безопасно как я понимаю.
2. Делать проверку на сервере и отдавать страницы по роли? Но хотелось бы весь фронтенд иметь на клиенте, так как не хочется каждый раз ссылаться к серверу за страницей.
3. Либо сохранять роль пользователя в куках и при переходе чекать с сервером на соответствие роли?

Еще читал про вариант с templates cache, что можно  получить сразу все вьюхи, записать их в кеш и работать с ними из кеша.

Как быть? Как лучше эту модель реализовать? Безопасность важна, т.к. происходит работа с финансами и личными данными. Но и хотелось бы оставить быстрый отклик сайта.

Поделитесь опытом реализация.

Comment: В любом случае сервер перед выполнением операции должен проверить права, поэтому вполне безопасно сохранять роль в куки/сессию.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian И при каждом state чекать на соответствие с сервером? Данных в куках или сессии можно изменить и тем самым получить доступ куда не надо. Куки на сколько я знаю вообще можно перекинуть на другой пк и оттуда спокойно получить доступ в лк пользователя.

Comment: В том то и дело, что никакие изменения на клиентской стороне (и не только подмена куков, но и даже скриптов) не должны открывать доступ к запрещенным ресурсам. Т.е. в любом случае сервер каждый запрос обязан проверить. Ну, а то, что можно токен увести на другой компьютер, тут уже ничего не поделаешь, как его не храни, хоть в куках хоть в локал стораж. Разве только привязывать на сервере к IP. но это неудобство для пользователей некоторое.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian. благодарю. Прояснил для себе немного. 
Хотелось бы еще мнения посмотреть. Подожду.